# Why does JSON.parse(str) into String?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jsonstore

I try to use `JSON.parse();` to parse a string into a JavaScript object, but when I call `console.log(object.constructor.name);` after, it gives me "String".

I tried using `parse` twice rather than once, but then it gave me an error.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
var yes = document.getElementById("yes");
var no = document.getElementById("no");
var dataString = "";
const endpoint = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/4037b406bb44de85c5dd50eb1a6472bedb79f447e747412695637c2784cbe43f';

function writeToDatabase(arr) {
    alert(arr);
    (async function() {
            // Send a post request, saving some data
            post_response = await fetch(endpoint, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(arr)
            });
            /*
            // console.log the result
            console.log(`POST response:`, await post_response.json())
            */
    })();
}
function readFromDatabase() {
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

    console.log(data);
        dataArr = data;
        console.log(dataArr);
  });
}

yes.onclick = function() {
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log("full data: " + data);

        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data = data['result'];

        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log("result array only: " + data);

        data = JSON.parse(data);// object.contructor.name
        console.log("after parse: " + data);
        console.log("data type is: " + data.constructor.name);

        data[userInput.value] = "YES";
        console.log("final string to write to database: " + data);
        writeToDatabase(data);
    });
}



no.onclick = function() {
    dataString = "{"+userInput.value+": "+"NO"+"}"
    writeToDatabase(dataString);
}
```

I expected it to convert to a Javascript Object so I could add an item, but instead, it stays as a string and so I can't add an item.

CODE: https://repl.it/@ErichBuelow/JsonStore-using-JS
VIEW: https://jsonstore-using-js--erichbuelow.repl.co/

Comment: Could you attempt to create a working example of what you are dealing with and at least share an example of the response -> `JSON`  you are using. Thank you.

Comment: I thought it would give me Object?

Comment: Where? Be a lot more specific. Whole question is far too vague

Comment: Not sure but I think you don't need to parse anything, you already got a [`Body.json` as response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)... so you can directly operate on that `data Object` with JS!

Comment: So the ultimate goal is to update the object on the database, so I was trying to read the old data, parse it into an object, add to the object, then parse into a string and overwrite the old one on the database

Comment: https://jsonstore-using-js--erichbuelow.repl.co/

Comment: @ErichBuelow Do a `console.log(typeof data)` and if it says `Object` you're good to go with `data.myNewProp = "My New Value"`

Comment: If I could just add to the data on the database rather than overwrite that would be even better

Comment: @ErichBuelow that depends on your backend logic... If you can just send a `"YES"` and let the backend overwrite it.

Comment: @Roko C.Bujan I am using JSONstore.io and using fetch in the javascript

Comment: @ErichBuelow seems like you can always use the `PUT` method.

Comment: link to all code: https://repl.it/@ErichBuelow/JsonStore-using-JS

Comment: @ErichBuelow I'll take a look

Comment: @Roko C. Bujan For some reason the PUT method overwrites it too

Comment: @ErichBuelow in short, what you're up to?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm trying to save data to the database... that's all... as you can tell I'm inexperienced

Comment: @ErichBuelow I'm just trying to understand, currently you have: `[object Object] { ok: true, result: "{test: NO}"}` in your database. What's the `result` for? What's the `ok` for? So clicking the buttons what do you want to update in the database? And what's the `userInput` input for? What are you building?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the ok: true and result were like that when I started, I don't really want them and the userInput is to get a name from the input field

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan thank you for your time! I think I have it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the data at the URL:

```
{"result":"{test: NO}","ok":true}
```

`response.json()` then converts that to a JavaScript object with two properties (`result` (a string) and `ok` (a boolean).

`data = JSON.stringify(data)` converts it back to JSON, reversing the effect of `response.json()`.

`data = JSON.parse(data);` reverse it again giving you the aforementioned object ones more.

`data = data['result'];` extracts the `result` property, giving you the string `"{test: NO}"`.

`data = JSON.stringify(data);` gives you the JSON representation of that string.

`data = JSON.parse(data);` reverses that giving you the string again.

> I tried using parse twice rather than once, but then it gave me an error.

It isn't clear where you tried this, but if you tried to parse `{test: NO}` then it errored because that string is not valid JSON. `{ "test": "NO" }` would be valid JSON, but the quotes are missing.

Having strings of JSON embedded in JSON is just silly though. It would be better to express the original JSON as:

```
{
    "result": {
        "test": "NO"
    },
    "ok": true
}
```

Comment: I modified some of the code based on your answer and it works much better, so thank you.

Comment: I'm having some trouble though, because I can only add up to 2 pieces of data before I get the following error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)